# Is there a sophisticated method of removing embedded image tags in a single text file?

Tags: r

I am trying to clean up my EDGAR web scraped text files, but I have many embedded graphics tags for .gif, .jpg, .png etc in my EDGAR financial disclosure. The text file has standard text; however, there is a vast layer of graphics tags at the end.

I am trying to **"Remove graphics (ASCII encoded graphics) —embedded graphics increase by orders of magnitude the character count and file size of the 10-K documents. The inclusion of graphics in 10-K filings has increased each year. All encoded graphics must be purged, or document size-related variables will be severely affected."** This is taken from an internet appendix of a research article.

I have added a snippet of the embedded graphics tags; the line continues for many lines of text.

```
<BR>
<!-- TOCEXISTFLAG -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>5
<FILENAME>g110352qxi001.gif
<DESCRIPTION>G110352QXI001.GIF
<TEXT>
begin 644 g110352qxi001.gif
M1TE&.#=ABP!D '<  "'^&E-O9G1W87)E.B!-:6-R;W-O9G0@3V9F:6-E "P
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ML:/'CR!#BAQ)LJ3)DRA3JES)LJ7+ES E_@,P <"_F35GZ@1 ;N=-<C&#1IQ
M+EBP \:,'CUPM"E2IDC) 15*5>&_ \6R%M*:M>O6KF )&:M*]N $K,6^J@6;
MUFM7J67C"KSZE2O7NFS]% M64R[9?T4+"19<S #AP8C;;CT@U1BYOGYCTC5L
M@'+ERH4H(\Y,@) "#PH.S(P<D]P!R@0*$4BM>K!AU899$P+M@3%IR:=3IS9
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M'ZW\]XG7B&-J50,/N^P#01;,NEUK/T %01^K^_Q-TQCJK$<3X#S;:/+AP?\
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M0!U\@ PL+!K4!0CC;P_UZ$FM*0Q_HC2=L(!)35XQ3X_.=*;I!"I"_[E,/@"
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6"""!A"4+%"@+_0>!!T%]&H@0 0$ .P$!

end
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>6
<FILENAME>g110352qyi001.gif
<DESCRIPTION>G110352QYI001.GIF
<TEXT>
begin 644 g110352qyi001.gif
M1TE&.#=A>P!C '<  "'^&E-O9G1W87)E.B!-:6-R;W-O9G0@3V9F:6-E "P
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MVJ3*P, #DPZN2K<QQ[U!$Q @0%7SY\X-0)^NBH%U!@FR:]?.RG7RCOJ>"_]
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MH$(^: 8S9) MFF !.P(0@#.8X7$-P  +,=" %R9$'YCX0B(:X+F!:,(,*VC
...
```

Another snippet

```
</BODY>
</HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>32
<FILENAME>logo_nationaltobacco.jpg
<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC
<TEXT>
begin 644 logo_nationaltobacco.jpg
M_]C_X  02D9)1@ ! 0$"6 )8  #_X@H@24-#7U!23T9)3$4  0$   H0
M  (0  !M;G1R4D="(%A96B                !A8W-P05!03
M                        ]M4  0    #3+
M                                              ID97-C    _
M 'QC<')T   !>    "AW='!T   !H    !1B:W!T   !M    !1R6%E:   !
MR    !1G6%E:   !W    !1B6%E:   !\    !1R5%)#   "!   " QG5%)#
M   "!   " QB5%)#   "!   " QD97-C         ")!<G1I9F5X(%-O9G1W
M87)E('-21T(@24-#(%!R;V9I;&4              ")!<G1I9F5X(%-O9G1W
M87)E('-21T(@24-#(%!R;V9I;&4
M            =&5X=     !#;W!Y<FEG:'0@07)T:69E>"!3;V9T=V%R92 R
M,#$Q %A96B        #S40 !     1;,6%E:(                     !8
M65H@        ;Z(  #CU   #D%A96B        !BF0  MX4  !C:6%E:(
M     "2@   /A   ML]C=7)V        !      %  H #P 4 !D '@ C "@
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M,C(R,C(R,O_  !$( KP+"0,!(@ "$0$#$0'_Q  ?   !!0$! 0$! 0...

M
5                         /_9

end
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</SEC-DOCUMENT>
```

The point is to eliminate these tags and make the text file cleaner and more preprocessed. Is there a more sophisticated method for solving this problem?

I guess removing everything from "begin 644" to "end" could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have solved it myself :) It seems that the REGEX expression below worked on this.

```
X = gsub("GRAPHIC.*?end","",X)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).